# Using Outlook 2007 as PoP client with Gmail account

Tags: gmail, microsoft-outlook-2007

I recently started using outlook-2007 with my gmail account. I am using PoP settings in Outlook-2007 to access my gmail. In my gmail settings i have set the option as : Enable POP for mail that arrives from now on

1] How can download some messages from past already received in my gmail inbox to my outlook inbox ?

2] How can i selectively download messages from gmail to my outlook.

thank you.

-AD

Comment: Try marking them as unread. Short of that you can't. That is the pop3 protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably be better served by using IMAP instead of POP, it will provide you with more control over your email.

Here's how http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=75726

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go into your gmail account and mark all email as unread.  Then go into your settings and change the pop option to Enable POP for all mail (even mail that's already been downloaded) but you better make sure the email you have already pulled into Outlook because this could cause you to have many duplicates.